# Wrong person in the company is getting the "App store connect" review stage changes emails

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

This is the first time that i'm the person who is uploading and app to the app store when i am not the sole developer and technical person in the IOS position and I have an issue.

I'm the person that uploaded the app to the app store and "App review information" i filled my details. But my boss is getting the review changes Emails and i need to change that so i will receive them.

The only place i can think that he is in an i am not is that he is the Technical person in the "Arguments tax and banking section". There can be only one person over there but he is not the developer. He needs to stay there and i need to receive the mails for the review progress.

Is there a way to do that? I'm, guessing i'm not the first one that come across that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it...
Selecting my account and adding me as receiving mail for app store change fixed the issue.